# Google Sheet color rows 2 by 2

Tags: google-sheets

I cannot seem to find a way on how to color 2 rows in a row. All tutorials are to color alternating rows.

Namely, this is the situation

```
A1:O1 Header Title
A2:02 Header Subtitle
A3:O3 Name
A4:O4 Value
A5:O5 Name
A6:O6 Value
A7:O7 Name
A8:O8 Value
...
```

Title rows are colored manually.
I need to color rows 3 and 4 in 1 color, rows 5 and 6 in another color. Then again rows 7 and 8 in the first color. And so on.

Any ideas what custom formula in the conditional formatting should be?

I cannot use `unique` formula as nothing is unique here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Apply Conditional Formatting to A3:[*last column and row to which you want this applied*].

Choose "Custom formula is" and enter the following formula:

```
=ISEVEN(ROUND(ROW()/2))
```

Set the background color and Save.

Then set up a second Conditional Formatting rule, applying to the same range. Again, choose "Custom formula is" and enter the following formula:

```
=ISODD(ROUND(ROW()/2))
```

Set the background color and Save.

**HOW IT WORKS:**

By dividing all row numbers in half and then ROUNDing them, you essentially pair them. For instance Row 3 divided in half is 1.5, which rounded up is 2; *and* Row 4 divided in half is 2, which rounded up is still 2.

Then the ISEVEN and ISODD alternate every other pair of rows.

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot!